# Understanding rsyslog log format and filtering

Tags: linux, ubuntu, syslog, rsyslog

I am working on filtering logs from syslog and forwading to another log.

I am able too capture/filter the log based on "**internal-sftp**". By using

```
if $programname == 'internal-sftp' then /var/log/sftp/sftp.log
```

above is working.

But I am unable to filter based on this "**lstat name**". I troed pri, syslogtag et., below is the log format.

```
Apr 24 02:16:30 ip-10-0-10-22 internal-sftp[4714]: lstat name "/settlement/universalpay/test_deletez.log"
```

So, how can I filter the line containing **lstat name** based on condition. Which properties i should use.

Below is sample code which I am trying.

```
if $programname == 'internal-sftp' then {
        if $syslogfacility-text contains 'lstat name' then {
                action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/sftp/sftp_lstat_files.log" template="outfmt")
        }
        action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/sftp/sftp.log" template="outfmt")
        & stop 
}
```

Comment: It is probably in the `$msg` property. see [properties](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/properties.html).

Comment: I tried this and learnt "/settlement/universalpay/test_deletez.log"  this part is the $msg

Comment: Look through the [Reserved Template Names](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/templates.html#reserved-template-names). It might be the `$app-name`. If not, use the `RSYSLOG_DebugFormat` template to break out the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bala,

Could you please check as below

```
if $msg startswith ' lstat name' then { ....
```

make sure that you have space as shown above infront of ' lstat name'